# My object "uploadData" not showing information passed to it and just showing "FormData{}" on the console

Tags: angular, file-upload, angular6, mean-stack, angular-reactive-forms

I want to upload a file and so creating a new object which I want to pass to the server called "uploadData". I want to add values in this object from "uploadForm" object which is created using angular form builder. But on the console, it's just showing "FormData{}".

```
const uploadData = new FormData();
        this.uploadData.append("name", this.uploadForm.value.name);
        this.uploadData.append("sem", this.uploadForm.value.sem);
        this.uploadData.append("subject", this.uploadForm.value.subject);
        this.uploadData.append("material", this.uploadForm.value.material);
        this.uploadData.append("id", this.userId);
        this.uploadData.append("pdf",this.uploadForm.value.pdf, this.uploadForm.value.name);
        //this.updown.upload(this.uploadData).subscribe()
        console.log(this.uploadData);
```

form builder is

```
uploadForm = this.fb.group({
name: ['', Validators.required],
sem: ['', Validators.required],
subject: ['', Validators.required],
material: ['', Validators.required],
pdf: ['', Validators.required]
});
```

Pdf is a file so:

```
onImagePick(event: Event){
const file = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).files[0];
this.uploadForm.patchValue({ pdf : file });
this.uploadForm.get('pdf').updateValueAndValidity();
}
```

Comment: You use `this.updown.upload(this.uploadData)` but declare it as `const uploadData`. Remove the `this` keyword and you should be fine.

Comment: Another problem is that it's not showing data on the console and just showing "FormData{}"

Comment: See my answer, didn't fit in a comment

Comment: I just have updated my question so you can look at it if you want.

Comment: Well it doesn't help me answering you in any way but sure ! did you try my answer ?

Comment: Tried but still at the same position. Thanks for the help though. Will I stop getting answers now?

Comment: Well you shouldn't even got any, because you didn't provide a [mcve]. Consider making a new question with it, and you should have way more answers.

Answer (score 0):

You use `this.updown.upload(this.uploadData)` but declare it as const uploadData. Remove the this keyword and you should be fine.

For the other issue, FormDatas are immutable, meaning that `append` return a new Form Data instance.

Try using this code instead :

```
const uploadData = new FormData()
    .append("name", this.uploadForm.value.name)
    .append("sem", this.uploadForm.value.sem)
    .append("subject", this.uploadForm.value.subject)
    .append("material", this.uploadForm.value.material)
    .append("id", this.userId)
    .append("pdf",this.uploadForm.value.pdf, this.uploadForm.value.name);

    //this.updown.upload(this.uploadData).subscribe()
    console.log(this.uploadData);
```